# Problem with PDE Ansatz

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamic-programming

Im currently reading "A stochastic differential game of capitalism" of Leong and Huang, and they try solving the PDE
$$ -J_t^F(k) - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2k^2 J_{kk}^F(k) = e^{-\rho t} \{f'(k)-\overline{x} - (\delta + n - \sigma^2)k \} $$
where, $\sigma, \delta, n$ are given constants and $f$ a given function. Also, $k$ and $\overline{x}$ are functions of time. They try the solution $J^F(k,t) = e^{-\rho t} B k^2$, where $B$ is a constant. My problem is, after solving for $B$, they arrive at
$$ B = \frac{f'(k) - \overline{x} -(\delta +n - \sigma^2)k}{(p-\sigma^2)k},$$
so $B$ isn't a constant if $\overline{x}$ doesn't cancel the terms in the numerator. Furthermore, in **Proposition 3.5**, the condition for arriving at the above PDE imply $B = 1/(2k)$. So $B$ isn't a constant neither. Is there a mistake?

Comment: Are you sure $k$ is time dependent? Can you provide the exact statement from the paper?

Comment: @user619894 Yes, in fact, k is given by $dk = [s(f'(k) - x) - (\delta + n - \sigma^2) k]dt - \sigma k dW$ where $W$ is a Wiener process. They're solving for Nash Equilibrium controls $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{s}$.

Comment: They have a quite unfortunate notation. But the $k$ in their PDE is a simple real valued variable and not related to the SDE for $k$.

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question.